# Strange smell in August only

Tags: smell, slab

I have a strange smell (somewhat like decomp but its not) that has presented its self every August since 2009 and stays for 14 days. It comes on strong the second day and stays the same smell level for 12-13 days and goes away until the next year. I have had the plumbing inspected twice with a camera and 2 pest control companies that say its not rodents. I have bored holes in walls and used video scope to inspect inside walls looking for any signs of pests and have found nothing. The house is 2 story built in 2007 on concrete slab with no drainage issues around the house.

Comment: Any area in the house where it is the strongest?

Comment: What kind of climate is the house located in?  What season is it in August?

Comment: Including your location might be important here, as it could be caused by an indigenous animal or plant. For example, some areas are plagued by [stink bugs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_marmorated_stink_bug), who release a pungent aroma when threatened.

Comment: NE Atlanta Metro

Comment: Around the Master bedroom area which is the only single story part of the house.

Comment: I had 2 Pest control companies that could not find any type of creature.

Comment: Do you have carpets?

Comment: Sounds like a great time to take a vacation. In all seriousness is there a plant or flower that blooms around that time?

Comment: city water/sewer or well/septic system?  If septic system, is it located near the master bed and when do you have it maintained?

Comment: The Master Bed room is carpeted.

Comment: On sewer county sewer system. Video scoped to the main line in street.

Comment: Just some shrubs around the outside walls.

Comment: Check with neighbors, see if any have similar issues.  Nothing so far screams out, you must check this as you have already checked all the common areas.

Comment: I guess the only area left not checked is under the carpet.  You might have a colony of something under there that are otherwise not visible.  A carpet company can lift the carpet/pad and then stretch it back out again for just an hour/two of work.  Look for any water stains on the slab or excessive dirt/junk.  Also make sure to inspect the area between the wall and carpet tack strips.  You most likely will need to replace the carpet pad before it can be placed back down since a lot of installers will glue them to the slab.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because locating the source of a smell via the internet is not practical.

Answer (score 2):

Could there be a hidden floor drain in the area? It wouldn't explain why the timing is so regular, but it might be connected to something that does. I've dealt with a similar come-and-go odor problem in a commercial buidling that ended up being a 4 inch open floor drain that was just carpeted over when the building was turned into offices. That drain line connected into a drainage system that was tied to a nearby building that housed a chicken processing operation. You can imagine what sorts of things were washed down their pipes. It typically only smelled during the dry season, I suppose because some elbow trap between us and the odor dried out.

Comment: Thank you for contributing your experience with this vexing and annoying problem!